# Why does this command line code skip every other characters?

Tags: cmd, command, line

**Problem:**
I'm struggling to figure out why this command line code skips every other characters?

The %INPUT_NAME% var looks like this: "Justified-S06E12-SindependenceDay-36770989-0"

**The result of the code below:** Instead of returning "Justified", I get something like "Jsife061".

**The Goal:** To strip out everything after the first "-" and use the result (In this case "Justified") to perform a search.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Current Code Iteration:

```html
::Remove any Spaces from Search Name
set HAYSTACK=%INPUT_NAME%
set HAYSTACK=%HAYSTACK: =%
echo.%HAYSTACK%


SET SEARCHNAME=
:GetUntilDash_loop

IF %HAYSTACK% EQU "" GOTO :EOF
   IF %HAYSTACK:~0,1% EQU "-" GOTO :SearchFile
      SET SEARCHNAME=%SEARCHNAME%%HAYSTACK:~0,1%
        echo.%HAYSTACK:~0,1%
      SET HAYSTACK=%HAYSTACK:~1%

GOTO :GetUntilDash_loop

:SearchFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a much easier way to do this:

```
for /f "delims=-" %%i in ("%INPUT_NAME%") do set string=%%i
```

the `for` command divides your variable into "tokens". You can define, which char is the delimiter (in your case `-`). If you don't tell `for` which token to take, it takes the first one - exactly, what you want.

Comment: Brilliant, and much more efficient. I tend to always do things the hard way.. Thank You!